# Cache-Control: private in Spring-MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, cache-control

WebContentInterceptor is nice, but I can't find how to make it add the "private" directive to the CacheControl HTTP header.
I either need to subclass it, or use response.setHeader in my controllers.

Is there any other convenient way to do this?

Preferably something annotation based :-)

Comment: Are you saying you're absolutely against sub-classing WebContentInterceptor?  It looks like all you'd have to do is override preHandle and set the header there.

Comment: No, I'm saying I'd prefer to be able to have convenient but fine grained control over the cache-control directives on the controller method level. WebContentInterceptor works with the URL mapping. I was wondering if there already is a solution I could use before brewing my own. Probably not the best question in the history if StackOverflow...

Comment: I see what you're saying, you want "on-the-spot" declarative control without having to code it in place

Comment: Yes, especially as I may want to compose the different directives within the Cache-Control header ("private" vs "public" and "max-age" so far) with separate scopes. (e.g. one per controller, the other per method, possibly even from method logic?) Definitely not the best question in SO history, more like a Rubber Ducky session, sorry :-/

Comment: Bah don't worry about whether the question is valid or not, ask anyway, maybe someone has encountered it. Hopefully someone has seen this or has encountered this particular scenario.

Comment: There is a Jira out for this https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/foo4u/spring-mvc-cache-control. And it's annotation based :D.

It seems that Spring is taking into account adding this in a future version: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7129.

Meantime, it seems that it's included in v4.2.